# Libgdx Rendering Bitmap font to pixmap texture causes extremely slow rendering

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm using libgdx scene2d to render 2d actors. Some of these actors originally included scene2d Label actors for rendering static text. The Labels work fine but drawing ~20 of them on the screen at once drops the frame rate by 10-15 frames, resulting in noticeably poor rendering while dragging.

I'm attempting to avoid the Labels by pre-drawing the text to textures, and rendering the textures as scene2d Image actors. I'm creating the texture using the code below:

```
    BitmapFont font =  manager.get(baseNameFont,BitmapFont.class);
    GlyphLayout gl = new GlyphLayout(font,"Test Text");

    int textWidth = (int)gl.width;
    int textHeight = (int)gl.height;
    LOGGER.info("textHeight: {}",textHeight);
    //int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    int width = textWidth;
    //int height = 500;
    int height = textHeight;

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

    FrameBuffer m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB565, width,height, false);
    m_fbo.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f,1f,1f,0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix4 normalProjection = new Matrix4()

            .setToOrtho2D(0, 0, width,  height);
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(normalProjection);

    spriteBatch.begin();

    font.draw(spriteBatch,gl,0,height);


    spriteBatch.end();//finish write to buffer

    Pixmap pm = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(0, 0, (int) width, (int) height);//write frame buffer to Pixmap

    m_fbo.end();

    m_fbo.dispose();
    m_fbo = null;
    spriteBatch.dispose();

    Texture texture = new Texture(pm);
    textTexture = new TextureRegion(texture);
    textTexture.flip(false,true);
    manager.add(texture);
```

I assumed, and have read, that textures are often faster. However when I replaced the Labels with the texture, it had the same, if not worse, affect on the frame rate. Oddly, I'm not experiencing this when adding textures from a file, which makes me think I'm doing something wrong in my code. Is there a different way I should be pre-rendering these pieces of text?

Comment: You said you had 20 labels. Are you creating 20 of these full-screen textures to draw all at once? That would almost certainly have worse performance than drawing individual labels. You would be trading drawing a moderate number of vertices for drawing many, many fragments.

Comment: No. I'm basically starting from scratch so I can really figure out what the issue is. I removed *all* the labels, and I'm rendering one single piece of text to a single texture, during initialization. Then I replaced all of those Labels with scene2d Images that all point to that single texture. So now I'm rendering 20 copies of the same texture, instead of 20 different labels. Without the Images my FPS is 60+ (But with many other file-based textures). As soon as I add the 20 copies of the same pre-rendered text texture it drops to 40-45, which creates noticeable stutter.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I should point out that in reality there are probably 100 Images of the texture, however they *are not visible* and so my assumption is that Libgdx is not calling draw methods on them. I believe this is accurate because there would have been *more significant* issues had I been attempting to render 100 Labels at once.

Comment: By 100 images, you mean 100 Image instances in your scene2d graph? I don't think scene2d does any actor culling with the view frustum, so if they are added to the graph, they are being drawn. Of course, if they're off-screen, once their vertices are projected in the vertex shader, they will have no fragments to draw with the fragment shader, so it shouldn't be a big impact in that sense. But if this is 100 different texture instances, there will be a lot of texture swapping going on even though those textures aren't visible.

Comment: No, just one. My proposed method creates *one* texture, and each Image references the same texture via a TextureRegion. So there is only one texture. My understanding from this question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114626/does-scene2dlibgdx-know-when-an-image-is-drawn-out-of-the-screen is that scene2d does cull actors that are not within the viewport.

Comment: scene2d Groups have an option to call `setCullingArea()` on them to set a rectangle that is used to cull drawing of children. This is not done automatically for you. You must manually set the culling area of the parent group. The people answering your linked question are plain wrong. You can check the source code to see for yourself that `setCullingArea()` is only used within the library for ScrollPane.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Odd because I've seen multiple people say that it *does* cull. But upon testing I can see that actors outside my view are being drawn, and the code only uses cullingArea, which doesn't appear to be set anywhere. So the next question is, how do I get the culling rectangle from the camera frustum?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I just added a quick frustum check in the draw() method of one of base actors and it pretty instantly fixed the FPS issues. It would still be nice to do this up at the stage level instead of for each actor, but it turns out that the excessive draw() calls on objects not in view was the issue. If you'd like to add that as an answer then I'll mark it.

Comment: I added an explanation of culling, but I still don't know why your baked textures are a bigger performance hit than the Labels, especially ones that are off screen and not culled. No fragment shader pixels have to be processed, but a Label obviously has many more vertices to process than the baked texture.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think I figured that part out. I assumed the original code, which drew labels,  was culling. That was incorrect. What that meant was that many extra Labels were drawn. The key is that not *all* of the extra Labels were drawn, due to logic in my code that set some of them to invisible. However, when I added the texture test, I did not apply the same visibility logic. Thus *all* actors were drawing the texture. So whereas the Label code was drawing some subset of Labels (still too many) the texture code was drawing the Image for all 200+ Actors. So performance was actually worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I think you can enable culling for the whole Stage by setting its root view to use a `cullingArea` matching the world width and height of the viewport. I would do this in `resize` after updating the Stage Viewport just in case the update affects the world width and height of the viewport.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    //...
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    stage.getRoot().setCullingArea(
        new Rectangle(0f, 0f, stage.getViewport().getWorldWidth(), stage.getViewport().getWorldHeight())
    );
}
```

It will only be able to cull Actors that have their x, y, width, and height set properly. This is true I think of anything in the scene2d UI package, but for your own custom Actors you will need to do it yourself.

If a child of your root view is a Group that encompasses more than the screen and many actors, you might want to cull its children, too, such that even if the group as a whole is not culled by the root view, the group can still cull a portion of its own children. To figure out the culling rectangle for this, I think you would intersect a rectangle of the group's size with the viewport's world size rectangle offset by -x and -y of the group's position (since the culling rectangle is relative to the position of the group it's set on).

Comment: This doesn't account for the fact that the culling area changes when you move the camera. The x,y of the rectangle needs to change. So it looks something more like: mainStage.getRoot().setCullingArea(
                new Rectangle(camera.position.x-mainStage.getViewport().getWorldWidth()/2, camera.position.y-mainStage.getViewport().getWorldHeight()/2, mainStage.getViewport().getWorldWidth(), mainStage.getViewport().getWorldHeight())
        );
This doesn't take zoom into account, so I'll have to work on that, but it's headed in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, yes I forgot to mention that. I exclusively use scene2d for UI, so I don't move its camera.